# ODatabaseRecordThreadLocal.INSTANCE.get() returning closed connections

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

In our application we are using GraphAPI and ObjectAPIs. When we attempt to get a connection however - we get one in a closed state.

In tracing through the code I came across pollGraphFromStack - which seems to be responsible for putting the last connection back on the thread local. However we are shutting down the database after every operation and therefore not expecting the closed connections to be on the stack.

What can we do to address this problem.?

I am on latest Orient version (2.1.9). Our application is multi-threaded and generally does not run into the error. But we are consistently getting the issue with JUnit - which simulates some code flows for us.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by nested connections being created. The scenario was that we had graph connection open while a call to a function opened a new document connection - and it all ended up in a bad state.